# How to access internet when connected to a remote VPN

Tags: sql-server, vpn

I am trying to synchronize to databases. One is MySQL (slave) that is accessible via normal internet connection. The other is a MSSQL(Master) database that is only accessible via VPN. I have the VPN connection established (External VPN) and active in windows and the synchronization software can connect to the MSSQL instance (Only when VPN connection is active). The trouble I am having is that I cannot connect to the MySQL database when the VPN connection is active. On the other hand, when the VPN connection is disabled and I am using a normal connection, I can access the MySQL database but not the MSSQL database. It seems like I would need to have both DB's either using the VPN or Standard Internet connection. Is there a way around this?

P.S: I am not a network specialist or DBA. Please try and be descriptive.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: This needs much more details how your routing looks and how the VPN is set up.

Answer (score 1):

Most VPNs will have two options for internet traffic

- send it via the VPN connection (usually called something like "Tunnel all")
- send it directly

Given that you can not connect to the slave when the VPN is connected I suspect that your VPN may be using the former option and the firewall that your VPN is using is blocking it for some reason.

Without more details of the VPN client you are using it is difficult to diagnose but you may wish to get in contact with the administrator of the VPN to see if they can help.

You might also want to try doing a ping/nslookup of the slave server to rule out a DNS issue when connected to the VPN